# Spring JPA save an already existing Entity of @OneToMany relationship

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 entities (I removed useless fields):

```
@Entity
public class ApkPermissions {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany
    @Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
    private Collection<Permission> declaredPermissions;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Permission {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String permissionName;
}
```

when I save the ApkPermissions entity for the first time through a CrudRepository I've no problems, but when I save another ApkPermissions with some Permission that already exists in the Permission table an exception is raised indicating the Unique Key violation of permissionName.

I found this solution:

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/cascade-jpa-hibernate-annotation-common-mistake/

that seems to fit my case (and is my current implementation), but it doesn't work.

I get the following error message:

```
could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [UK_l3pmqryh8vgle52647itattb9]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement",
```

From mysql:

```
UNIQUE KEY `UK_l3pmqryh8vgle52647itattb9` (`permission_name`)
```

---

Temporary solution is retrive all corresponding Permission searching by permissionName from a Repository. Then the save works fine.
It's logically correct but I hope that exists a simpler procedure...

Comment: Could you include the output of exception message?

Comment: I did it. Note that now I changed the relationship as @Pardeep suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OneToMany mapping, your permission table will have one extra column which will be a foreign key pointing to your ApkPermissions.
For Example:

```
ApkPermission           Permission
APK_ID | Name           Permission_ID | Name | APK_ID(FK)
1      | APK1            1            | P1   | 1
                         2            | P2   | 1
```

So you can not point same permission from any other ApkPermission record. Suppose, if you want to enter  2 | APK2 in ApkPermission and want to point P1 and P2 again. You can not do it with one to many relation unless you make P1 and P2 entry again in permission table. That will create duplicates. So you have two options here, either you drop the unique constraints(on permissionName) or you change the mapping to ManyToMany.

Comment: You're right, the correct relationship is ManyToMany... 
but the problem persists when I save an ApkPermission that has a Permission in declaredPermissions that  already exists in the db.

Comment: Did you try with manyToMany? You are gonna need one more join table in that case. and new entries will go in new join table. There are lot of examples available.With OneToMany, you have to insert new records. Otherwise it's not gonna make any sense.

Comment: If you still want to proceed with OneToMany (& that wont be normalized) then you can remove the unique constraint from permissionName as you are gonna have duplicates. I suggest give it a try with ManyToMany. One thing I would like to mention that hibernate save always makes an insert query if primary key is null. In that case, use saveOrUpdate. But if your record is there in DB then ID should not be null when you try to persist it otherwise it's always gonna assume it as a new record.

Comment: Yes, now I'm using a  ManyToMany relationship, but I have to fetch the Permission if they are already exists in the db